# Access-VBA - Compile Error with ConcatRelated - Previously worked

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm receiving a compile error attempting to run a query using Allen Browne's `ConcatRelated` function.

> Compile error: in query expression 'SELECT MbrNbr, EventIndex, ConcatRelated("EventIndex", "PlayerResults", MbrNbr = 123456)'.

The mystery is *I know* this executed successfully previously.

**Note:** This is my first time using MS Access for a project, so it's my first time using Allen's `ConcatRelated` function.  I have to assume there is something obvious I'm missing. I've coded in MS Excel VBA for about 10 years.

I do have a query that is more complex than the example below but I put together this *very basic* query just to test if there is something amiss with my setup all of a sudden.

I've googled all I can to attempt to resolve this and all code examples seem to show I have it correct.

**Setup:**

- `ConcatRelated` is saved as a function named `Concat_Related_Data`. I've read the function name **cannot** be `ConcatRelated`.
- The simple query receiving the error is:

  ```
  SELECT MbrNbr, EventIndex, ConcatRelated("EventIndex", "PlayerResults", MbrNbr = 123456) 
  FROM PlayerResults;
  ```

  **Note**: I copied Allen's example and simply edited it with a call to one of my tables. Field `MbrNbr` is defined as "Number".

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look here http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html I saw that the third parameter is defined as a string parameter too (as expected) and not as a boolean.

So I think you should use this:

```
SELECT MbrNbr, EventIndex, ConcatRelated("EventIndex", "PlayerResults", "MbrNbr = 123456") FROM PlayerResults;
```

Info: The third parameter of `ConcatRelated` also is a string here, containing your condition.

Comment: Thanks Unhandled.
I did miss that and made that change but still receiving that error.
    SELECT MbrNbr, EventIndex, ConcatRelated("EventIndex", "PlayerResults", "MbrNbr = 123456") FROM PlayerResults;

(smashing.my.head.on.a.brick.wall.BILL)

Comment: I created a new database containing the table you described and the procedure `ConcatRelated` (copied into a new module from Allens site). Your query runs fine here. Strange. Can you post the procedure you use? Did you modify it?

Comment: Another question: Can you compile the code in the VBE without an error?

Comment: same error in VBA
Here is the actual Query
    SELECT MbrNbr, EventIndex, ConcatRelated("EventIndex", "PlayerResults", "MbrNbr = 123456")

FYI: I did not modify Allen's function. Straight copy-n-paste

Comment: FYI: I have the above in a "Query" and a VBA module.  Both give a compile error.

Comment: When you compile the VBA, isn’t there any code marked, where the error occurs?

Comment: Yes,  On the OpenRecordset that performs the SQL with the ConcatRelated code.   The VBA code is a copy of the Access Query

Comment: Please show us your code. Currently it is more guessing than helping.

Comment: I have an old version of the database.  I copied the module with the ConcatRelated function to it plus cut-n-paste the query code into a new query in the old version.   It works fine there. Even the VBA code with the SQL works there. There is something odd in my current version that that chokes on the ConcatRelated.   I believe my SQL and the module with the ConcatRelated function are fine. Now to find the gremlin in this current version of the database.  Sigh
Thanks for all you time and assistance Unhandled!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by @UnhandledException; where you state:

> `ConcatRelated` is saved as a function named `Concat_Related_Data`. 
>   I've read the function name **cannot** be `ConcatRelated`.

For clarity: the code for the function should be copied "as is" from Allen Browne's site into a new VBA module, without changing the function name.

However, when saving the VBA module, the **module** should be named something different to `ConcatRelated`, else you will receive a type-mismatch error when trying to invoke the function.

---

Note that if you are using the code within SQL code that is represented using a string in VBA, you will need to either escape the double-quotes (to ensure that they remain in the SQL code), or use single-quotes instead, i.e.:

```
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MbrNbr, EventIndex, ConcatRelated('EventIndex', 'PlayerResults', 'MbrNbr = 123456') FROM PlayerResults")
```

Or:

```
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MbrNbr, EventIndex, ConcatRelated('EventIndex', 'PlayerResults', 'MbrNbr = 123456') FROM PlayerResults")
```

Comment: Thanks Lee Mac. I have named the function something other than "ConcatRelated".  Sorry, if I was clear above.

Comment: @billgeo The point was that you don't need to name the **function** something other than `ConcatRelated` but rather named the **VBA module** something other than `ConcatRelated`. The function should remain named as is, or you'll also need to rename all of the return calls.

Comment: Ah... I see what you're getting at. My response was ambiguous  Yep, The function is "ConcatRelated" and the module is something else.

Comment: @billgeo Based on information in your comments, I have updated my answer above.